# WPF not recognizing KeyGestures/shortcut keys

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two buttons with shortcut keys ('U' & 'UA'). This is working fine if both buttons are enabled.

- button1 has shortcut key 'U'
- button2 has shortcut key 'UA'

If the button1 ('U' shortcut) is disabled then it is not recognizing the 'UI' shortcut key for button2 (button2 is enabled)

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Please post relevant code here.

Comment: Agreed with Rohit, we need to see what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

I tried specifying the short cut considering the scenario you said. It worked fine.
Please specify the code so that I could work on it and get back with solution.